# Error LNK2001 with variables inside namespace

Tags: c++, variables, namespaces, lnk2001

I have 2 files:

1. tier1.h
2. tier1.cpp

In tier1.h I have:

```
//code

namespace variab
{
  int x...; float tpl...; //etc
}

namespace universal
{
  using namespace variab;
  //some functions prototypes
}
```

In tier1.cpp there are the functions defined. Some of the functions are in imbricated namespaces, like: universal::extG::. These functions are using the variables found in variab namespace.

In the source file, where main is to be found, tier1.h is included.

When I try to compile the program, it gives me errors pointing to the variables found in variab namespace. The error is the same everywhere. This is how it looks:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int * variab::st" (?st@variab@@3PAHA)
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header file you're *declaring* the variables in the namespace. You need to only declare them with the `extern` keyword:

```
namespace variab
{
    extern int x;
    extern float tpl;
    // etc...
}
```

Then in a source file you do the definition:

```
namespace variab
{
    int x;
    float tpl;
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: It works. But could you explain me why do this? What's the logical idea?

Comment: In C++ (as in C) most everything is divided into *declarations* and *definitions*. When you *declare* something (like a `extern` variable or a function prototype in a header file) you only tell the compiler that something exists, but it doesn't actually define the thing. This has to be done in one single place only, like in a source file.